# How to Pipe traffic from one NIC through Squid, dual nic system

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

So I have 16.04 running Squid as a proxy for my children's devices.

Right now all devices have a hard-code IP and proxy setting.

I have two Wireless Networks.

For name sake:
NIC 1> Main Network  192.168.0.0
Nic 2> WI-FI ROUTER 192.168.1.0

I would like all traffic from the WIFI Router to pipe through the proxy without having to hardcode the proxy on those devices. I want the WIFI Router to handle DHCP. I don't want to set DHCP up on my Ubuntu box at the moment.

I don't see a setting on the router to pass through the proxy:port. So essentially I want the WIFI Router to just act as an AP and all internet traffic is filtered through Squid.  Local Traffic should be unaffected and pass freely.

One of the caveats is I have Roku TV that will be on the WiFi Router that would stream Netflix, and other services, so I may need to open some ports, which I can allow in squid.conf if needed.

I have spent some time searching google but can't seem to use the right search term or find the right article.

Can anyone direct me on if this is possible and what settings/commands  I would need to take to make this happen?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you want to implement is a [transparent proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy).

> Also known as an intercepting proxy, inline proxy, or forced proxy, a
>   transparent proxy intercepts normal communication at the network layer
>   without requiring any special client configuration. Clients need not
>   be aware of the existence of the proxy. A transparent proxy is
>   normally located between the client and the Internet, with the proxy
>   performing some of the functions of a gateway or router.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to implement is "Web Proxy Auto Discovery".
This question on StackOverflow has many informations about it.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/191023/3552972
And also this article on Wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol

You will have to setup at least a DNS server and a simple Web server to make it work.

Comment: I'm not looking to detect the proxy automatically, I'm wanting all internet traffic from my WiFI Router to tunnel through squid for filtering. Thank you for the comment.